# Problema com a extensão do PDO Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, apache

Uso o apache+php7+postgres no Ubuntu e funciona de boa.

Mas agora quis fazer a instalação a mão no Windows 8.1 e encontrei um problema:

Instalei o Apache 2.4, PHP 7.1, e o Postgres.

O apache funcionou de boa, mas quando vou testar meu projeto me gera o seguinte erro:

> Erro: could not find driver Conexão inexistente!

No inicio do meu `httpd.conf`

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php711/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "c:/php711"
```

No meu `php.ini` estão descomentados:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

Não sei se essa imagem ajuda, mas no `phpinfo()` me retorna isso!

[image: Trecho do phpinfo()]

Comment: Como está a config extension_dir ? tente colocal o path completo até o diretório das extensions e reinicie o apache (importante reiniciar).

Comment: Bom dia, antes da PDO certifique que você tenha a **pgsql** instalada e configurada corretamente, pode executar o php.exe direto na linha de comando do Windows, experimente `php --ri pgsql`, logo no início deve constar algo como _PostgreSQL Support => enabled_, depois vem a versão e demais informações.

Comment: Não sei se é isso, mas você já verificou se existe as .dlls, no system32, pois com você fez a instalação individual do Apache 2.4, PHP 7.1, e o Postgres os drives podem não ter sido incorporados ao windows, tente copiar as dll que você descomentou lá no php.ini que estão em php/ext/ para o system32 e ou sysWOW64 (64bits), ou se você tiver uma necessidade imediativa de resolver esta situação, instale o xampp ou wamp, acredito que ambos podem criar já o ambiente completo que você busca. Download Xampp: https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/download.html

Comment: @FernandoMertins quando eu coloco este comando, me gera um monte de erros, mas eu verifiquei que ele procura em:
C:\php\ext...

E minha pasta do php é C:\php771

Comment: Olá, que erros...? Testei agora num Win7 mas com PHP 5.5 e deve mostrar `Extension 'pgsql' not present.` ~ou~ as informações da lib. Sugestão reomeça do zero... boa sorte.

Comment: Já fiz do zero 2x :/

Comment: Tem algum WAPP server? Tem o do bitnami, mas volta e meia me da problema no ubuntu, tem outro?